# Intent Redirection Your app(s) are vulnerable to Intent Redirection

Tags: android

our Application has been rejected repeatedly in recent weak because of "intent redirection". "Your app(s) are vulnerable to Intent Redirection."
and we couldn't find location of this warning .
Do you know how we could resolve this problem
please guide us to find resolution.
thanks a lot for your help.
and our code is as follows:
Below is my build.gradle file.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.KartikeswaraMatrixAccess.karma100"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 12
        versionName "1.0.12"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {

        debug {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.crowdfire.cfalertdialog:cfalertdialog:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.gdacciaro:iosdialog:1.0.3'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.+'
    //volly lib
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    //lib
    implementation files('libs\\jsoup-1.7.2.jar')
    //auto smsm
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:17.5.1'
    implementation 'com.chaos.view:pinview:1.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    //firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:20.0.0'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
**My android manifest file**


 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.karma100">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" />

    <application
        android:name=".webservices.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:allowClearUserData="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_sq2"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_cir2"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Karma100"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup,android:label"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
        tools:targetApi="n">
        <activity
            android:name=".Abouts100KarmaPage.WebViewPolicy"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CateoryPageDetails.CategoryViewDetails"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Abouts100KarmaPage.Abouts100Karma"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ProfileDetailsPage.ProfileDetailsPageActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".HistoryDetailsPage.ChatActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".HistoryDetailsPage.ViewTicketsPage"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".HistoryDetailsPage.ConactSupportPage"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ServiceInsurancePage.Service_InsurancePage_2"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ServicePayLoanPage.Service_PayLoanPage_2"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ServicePayLoanPage.Service_PayLoanPage"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ServiceInsurancePage.Service_InsurancePage"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ServiceFightPage.Service_FightPage"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PushNotificationPageDetails.NitificationDetailsPage_1"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".HistoryDetailsPage.HistoryActivityPage_2"
            android:exported="false" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/k_logo_default" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/purple_700" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="default_notification_channel_id" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MyReferalPage.MyReferal"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ForgotPasswordPage"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ChangePasswordPage"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ServiceBookCylinderPage.Service_BookCylinderPage2"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ServiceBookCylinderPage.Service_BookCylinderPage"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ServiceFastTagPage.Service_FastTagPage2"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ServiceFastTagPage.Service_FastTagPage"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ServiceBroadbandPage.Service_BoardbandPage2"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ServiceBroadbandPage.Service_BoardbandPage"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ServicePostPaidPage.Service_PostpaidPage2"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ServicePostPaidPage.Service_PostpaidPage"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ServiceElectricityPage.Service_ElectricityPage2"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ServiceElectricityPage.Service_ElectricityPage"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ServiceDTHPage.Service_DTHPage2"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ServiceMobilePage.Service_MobileFaildMessage"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ServiceMobilePage.Service_MobileTransactionMessage"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ServiceMobilePage.Service_MobileSuccessMessage"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ServiceMobilePage.Service_MobileRechargePage"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ServiceMobilePage.Service_MobilePageContact"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ServiceMobilePage.Service_MobilePage_2"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".UpdateProfileDetails"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".OtherServicesPage.OtherServicesMoreSearchProductPage"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ServiceDTHPage.Service_DTHPage"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ServiceMobilePage.Service_MobilePage"
            android:exported="false"
            android:windowDisablePreview="false" />
        <activity android:name=".MoreServiceDetailsPage.MoreServicesPage" />
        <activity android:name=".LoginOTPVerificationPage" />
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterPage"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginPage"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".SmsBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreenPage"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="karma100.page.link"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".PushNotificationPageDetails.FirebaseMessageReceiver"
            android:exported="false"
            android:stopWithTask="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".PushNotificationPageDetails.Myfirebaseinstanceidservice"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:stopWithTask="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please contact playstore support team, they will guide you for better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact google android team through your support section, they will keep guide you for deployment.